# How to import mysql sql file into microsoft visio 2007?

Tags: sql, import, visio

Does anyone know how to import a mysql sql file into microsoft visio 2007, and then generate a database chart automatically?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it.

I just create database in mysql with sql file, and then i use reverse engineering to build a visio chart.

the link will be useful for that. [here](http://sajjadhossain.com/2009/02/12/reverse-engineering-mysql-database-with-microsoft-visio/)

[EDIT]: Add The content of the post.

1.Download the latest MySQL ODBC connector from MySQL site. You may find it here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html.

2. After downloading install the connector.
3. Now open Microsoft Visio and open Database Model Diagram template (you may find it under Software and Database group).
4. From Database menu click on Reverse Engineer. You will see the Reverse Engineer wizard.
5. Click on the New button.
6. Select System Data Source.
7. Click Next.
8. Select MySQL ODBC driver from the list.
9. Click Next and then Finish. MySQL Connector/ODBC Data Source Configuration window will open.
10. Give a name to the datasouce, database server host, user name, password and select the database you want to reverse engineer. Remember, the list of database will be shown if you have provided correct information.
11. Click on Ok. Now you will find the data source in Data Source list.
12. Select the newly created data source and click Next. The regular wizard for reverse engineering will start.

Thanks.